# Kivy Switch on_active

Tags: python, callback, switch-statement, kivy

I want to use a Kivy Switch to turn something on/off. I am trying to stick with: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.switch.html , but there is no .kv example.

I have the following code, abstracted to the problem.

main.py:

```
def PID_an_aus(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            do something
        else:
            do something else
```

kv File:

```
Switch:
    on_active: root.PID_an_aus()
```

The GUI is working properly as long as I don't click on the switch. As soon as I click on the switch, the Programm closes without an error.

I feel a bit stupid right know, can someone enlighten me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is deblared as...

```
def PID_an_aus(self, instance, value):
```

...but you call it with...

```
on_active: root.PID_an_aus()
```

The problem is that you didn't call it with any arguments, whereas you declared it to expect two.

You could instead do

```
    on_active: root.PID_an_aus(self, self.active)
```

> As soon as I click on the switch, the Programm closes without an error.

Is there really no traceback here? You should get a 'function received wrong number of arguments (expected 3 got 1)' or similar.

Comment: works perfectly fine now, thank you. And no, there was no traceback :(